# How can i Delete AWS cookie when i close the browser?

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-applications, aws-application-load-balancer

So AWS ALB has session cookie named as AWSELBAuthSessionCookie-0. i want to delete these cookies when i close my browser window.

Reason being when i close my window and re-open it again for login.

I want ALB to route me to login form (prompt for username and password) of Oauth server every time rather than implicit login.

Comment: Use a private / incognito window or manually remove the cookie.

Comment: I am not asking for testing purpose, its for app devlopment. i wnat it programatically